# Publishing target in Sitecore 9

Tags: publishing

I am trying to configure a publishing target in Sitecore 9. I took the same steps I used to take in Sitecore 8, but it did not work. What I did:

- `\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config`  - contains the new connection strings to the web database
- `/sitecore/system/Publishing targets` – targets are listed
- `\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.config`  - I add :

```xml
<database id="web2" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" role:require="Standalone or Reporting or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery">
  <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
  <icon>Images/database_web.png</icon>
  <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
  <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
    <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
      <disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
      <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config" />
      </prefetch>
    </dataProvider>
  </dataProviders>
  <PropertyStore ref="PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='$(id)']" />
  <remoteEvents.EventQueue>
    <obj ref="eventing/eventQueueProvider/eventQueue[@name='$(id)']" />
  </remoteEvents.EventQueue>
  <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
    <archive name="archive" />
    <archive name="recyclebin" />
  </archives>
  <cacheSizes hint="setting">
    <data>100MB</data>
    <items>50MB</items>
    <paths>2500KB</paths>
    <itempaths>50MB</itempaths>
    <standardValues>2500KB</standardValues>
  </cacheSizes>
</database>
```

but i receive these errors :

> Could not find configuration node:
> PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='web2']
>
> Could not find configuration node: eventing/eventQueueProvider/eventQueue[@name='web2']

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add the missing nodes in your config. Sitecore has added these things in the database config in Sitecore9. So in your case -for a "web2" database-, add:

```
<eventing defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <eventQueueProvider defaultEventQueue="core">
    <eventQueue name="web2" type="Sitecore.Data.Eventing.$(database)EventQueue, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <param ref="dataApis/dataApi[@name='$(database)']" param1="$(name)" />
      <param hint="" ref="PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='$(name)']" />
    </eventQueue>
  </eventQueueProvider>
</eventing>
```

and

```
<PropertyStoreProvider defaultStore="core">
  <store name="web2" prefix="web2" getValueWithoutPrefix="true" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Properties.$(database)PropertyStore, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param ref="dataApis/dataApi[@name='$(database)']" param1="$(name)" />
    <param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseEventManager, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseCacheManager, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  </store>
</PropertyStoreProvider>
```

Haven't been able to fully test this (yet), but this should work.

Comment: its worked after applying it , but can anyone explain what these extra configuration meant specially PropertyStoreProvider

Comment: The PropertyStoreProvider seems to be a way to configure how the "Properties" table -which has been in Sitecore for quite a while- can be used. By default it's just working on your sql database with the default caching and event queue. I guess you can now override all that if you really want to..