# How to add the new publishing targets in sitecore 9.3

Tags: publishing

Can anyone helps me how to add the publishing targets in `Sitecore 9.3`

I followed below steps:

**Step 1:** Created a new connection “BO-Web” in the “ConnectionStrings.config” file.

**Step 2:** copied **"web"** to **"BO-Web"** node in “Sitecore.config”

**Step 3:** followed below article adding the additional configurations:

[Publishing target in Sitecore 9](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9207/publishing-target-in-sitecore-9)

**settings in sitecore.config** :

[image]

[image]
after performing the above configuration, getting below error, are there any additional configurations required.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add another `<store>` to `<ProperyStoreProvider>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
    <sitecore>
        <PropertyStoreProvider>
            <store name="BO-Web" prefix="BO-Web" getValueWithoutPrefix="true" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Properties.$(database)PropertyStore, Sitecore.Kernel">
                <param ref="dataApis/dataApi[@name='$(database)']" param1="$(name)" />
                <param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseEventManager, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
                <param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseCacheManager, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
            </store>
        </PropertyStoreProvider>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, Marek for your answer, I added another <store>, while publishing the item into new DB, getting the same error  "
Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='BO-Web']"

Comment: I don't know why you see that issue. From your question it looks like you added a database with id `BO-Web` to the configuration so it should work.

Comment: copied  "web"  to "BO-web"  node in “Sitecore.Eventing.config” and "Sitecore.PropertyStore.config", after this cleared the cache, then working fine, thanks to Marek.